# jQuery button's .click() function isn't happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery where I attempt to use `.click()` to count the symbols in a text input.  Clicking on the button does not do anything.
Please help, thanks.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text"id="id1"></input></div><br/><br/>
 <button onclick="#"id="id2"> Count Symbols</button>
 <p id="id1"></p>
<script>
$( document.#id1 )
  .click(function() {
    $( document.#id1 ).append( $( "#id2" ) );
    var n = $( "#id2" ).length;
    $( ).text( "There are " + n + " symbols.");
  })
 
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by reading how jQuery selectors work. `$( document.#id1 )` is not valid and neither is `$().text()` Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is really evident from the code shown that you need to study some basic tutorials. There is just too much wrong in that simple code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#id2' ).click(function() {
    var len = $('#id1').val().length;
    $('#id3').text('There are ' +len+ ' symbols');
  });

}); //END document.ready
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hjpb2xdo/)</kbd>

**Revised HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="id1" />
<br/><br/>
<button id="id2"> Count Symbols</button>
<p id="id3"></p>
```